# Reducing dot size scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, size, scatter

I am trying to scatter some points into an PIL image I created. The PIL images are huge, often over (107136*82944). The marker created by this line of code are way to big, and arent really just dots.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve my issue?

```py
plt.scatter(x_coordinate,y_coordinate, marker=',', s=0.001, c='r')
```

Comment: What is not working with your code?

Comment: My code is working fine, but the dots that are generated by it, are way to big.Furthermore, they are more like circles, not points